# i need to create a menu, which has multiple submenus

Tags: javascript, html, insert, drop-down-menu, submenu

Say i have a bunch of newspapers: The Times, The Independent, The Telegraph and BBC.

In a dropdown menu, I have: "The Times", "The Independent", "The Telegraph", "BBC", "BBC World news", and "BBC UK news".

What I want to happen, is that BBC world news and BBC uk news come up on a sub-list when I click BBC. This sub-list would insert itself a bit like the menu on the left side on this page http://www.stpaulsschool.org.uk , e.g. when I click "Daily Life", those other options come up.

right now i have a  `<form>`, then a `<select>`, then `<option>`s :

```
<form> 
    <select onchange="showRSS2(this.value)"> 
         <option value="">Select an RSS feed</option> <option value="Times">The Times</option> 
        <option value="Independent">The Independent</option> 
        <option value="BBC">BBC</option> 
        <option value="BBC-World">BBC World News</option> 
        <option value="BBC-UK">BBC UK</option> 
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you actually check the source code on http://www.stpaulsschool.org.uk/ to see how the menu is created there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">The Times</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Indepentent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Telegraph</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">BBC</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">BBC World news</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BBC UK news</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That should be enough.

Comment: right now i have a <form>, then a <select>, then <option>s :
<form>
<select onchange="showRSS2(this.value)">
<option value="">Select an RSS feed</option>
<option value="Times">The Times</option>
<option value="Independent">The Independent</option>
<option value="BBC">BBC</option>
<option value="BBC-World">BBC World News</option>
<option value="BBC-UK">BBC UK</option>
</select>
</form>

so where do i add the lists to this?

Comment: Why are you using a select with options when you want a menu like the one in http://www.stpaulsschool.org.uk/ ? Did you check the source code of the menu on that page?

Comment: I don't specifically want a menu like that, but that kind of thing in my drop down menu - it was like an example to explain what i'm looking for - so if you imagine that the whole menu on that site is in a dropdown, and that would work!

Comment: ok you will understand if you see it - its the middle bar on this: http://87.194.35.48:8081 - if the BBC world and uk appear below bbc, indented, when i click bbc,

Comment: So basically you are looking for the [`<optgroup>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTGROUP) tag.

Answer (score 0):

And the problem is? You simply create a list `<ul></ul>` and each member `<li></li>` contains two divs, like this:

```
<li>
   <div class="header">HEADER</div>
   <div class="submenu">
      <ul>
         <li>One</li>
         <li>Two</li>
         <li>Three</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</li>
```

with css `display: none;` set on `.submenu`. Then you add javascript for example jQuery `slideToggle` and style it. And you'r done.

Comment: what would my jQuery script look like and where should I put it?

Comment: The script is very simple: `$(document).ready(function(){ $("div.header").click(function(e){ $(this).next().slideToggle(); });});`. First you need to load jQuery in the head of the document, then use this script wherever you want (but *AFTER* jQuery). I advice to hold in a different file. I think you need some webdeveloping tutorial (obviously you lack some basics), but Stackoverflow is not the best place for this.